# Adding dateTime on Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

**This is my Controller**

```
public function storeAddSite(Request $request){

  if($request->submit=="Cancel")
      return redirect('/');


  if($request->submit=="Submit"){

      $site_name = $request->input('site_name');
      $site_url = $request->input('site_url');
      $crawl_id = $request->input('crawl_id');
      $ga_id = $request->input('ga_id');
      $uptime_code = $request->input('uptime_code');

      $email = $request->input('email');
      if($request->active == "active")
           $active = TRUE;
      else $active = FALSE;

      DB::table('sites')->insert(['site_name'=>$site_name,'site_url'=>$site_url,'deepcrawl_project_id'=>$crawl_id,'ga_id'=>$ga_id,'uptime_access_code'=>$uptime_code, 'recipients'=>$email, 'active'=>$active]);

  return redirect('/');
  }
}
```

This is my Migrations of my Site

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('sites', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('site_id');
        $table->string('site_name', 100);
        $table->string('site_url', 100);
        $table->integer('deepcrawl_project_id');
        $table->integer('ga_id');
        $table->string('uptime_access_code');
        $table->dateTime('monthly_email_date');
        $table->string('recipients')->unique();
        $table->boolean('active');
    });
}
```

Laravel Version 5.7
Php Version 7.2.8

Now here is the problem. I want to make a my monthly_email_date set to every first day of the month and want to store it also on my database. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you pass a `$monthly_email_date = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();` ( or similar) variable to your `->insert()` statement? Are you wanting MySQL (or whatever DB) to handle this automatically with a `default` value?

Comment: you need save `date` or `number?`

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos date

Comment: @TimLewis he answer you question put this `$monthly_email_date = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();`

Comment: @TimLewis laravel 5.7 was so confusing. Even I `use DateTime;` `use Carbon;` It always prompt an error "Class 'Carbon' not found" "Class 'DateTime' not found"

Comment: Yup, it's `use Carbon\Carbon;` :P Carbon is namespaced as a subclass of Carbon (which is confusing). Not sure about DateTime, probably don't need a `use` statement, could just do `new \DateTime()`

Comment: Why do you need a database column for storing the first day of the month?

Comment: @TimLewis thank you so much it worked!~ You can put that on answer so I can check it and I will also upvoted your comment.

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos its working already thank you. I up-voted you already =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel comes with `Carbon` PHP date library built in, so to create a date use the following:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Then, in your code:

```
$monthly_email_date = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(); 
// Would be 2018-09-01 00:00:00
```

Next, add that to your insert statement:

```
DB::table("sites")->insert([
  "site_name" => $site_name,
  "site_url" => $site_url,
  "deepcrawl_project_id" => $crawl_id,
  "ga_id" => $ga_id,
  "uptime_access_code" => $uptime_code, 
  "recipients" => $email, 
  "active" => $active,
  "monthly_email_date" => $monthly_email_date
]);
```

That will set your `monthly_email_date` column value to `2018-09-01 00:00:00`.